# TypeError converting fahrenheit to celsius in python

Tags: python

my code:

```
temperature_f = input('Please enter the temperature :')
print('The temperature is' , 1.8 / (temperature_f - 32) ,'centigrade')
```

run code:

```
Please enter the temperature :50
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Aryan\.vscode\py\test1.py", line 2, in <module>
    print('The temperature is' , 1.8 / (temperature_f - 32) ,'centigrade')
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

How can I fix this error?

I want to write a code that will convert fahrenheit to celsius for me but i am getting this error
Please tell me how I can fix this error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

You have to type cast your input

```
temperature_f = input(int('Please enter the temperature :'))
```

Answer (score 0):

type cast temperature string into `float`.

```
temperature_f = float(input('Please enter the temperature :'))
print('The temperature is' , 1.8 / (temperature_f - 32) ,'centigrade')
```